# Mutimodel JSON-BInding doesn´t work

Tags: sapui5

there is a context set on the view and I want to bind a property to a Label but that property needs to be bind to another model than the context.
I tried:

```
createLabel: function (){
  return new sap.m.Label({
      text: {labelname}
  }).bindProperty("visible","{/contextExisting}","detailModel");
```

also tried:

```
.bindProperty("visible","{detailModel>contextExisting}");
```

and:

```
.bindProperty("visible","{detailModel>/contextExisting}");
```

and the JSONModel:

```
this._detailJSONModel.setData({"contextExisting" : false});
```

the model is set globally with:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(this._detailJSONModel,"detailModel");
```

The Model isn´t created in the same .View but I can reach the model in the relevant view with:

```
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("detailModel");
```

I don´t know what´s wrong with the binding here. The Context-Binding is correct and working .

Comment: You can try to run is without the function `bindProperty`:
 `return new sap.m.Label({
      text: "{labelname}",
      visible: "{detailModel>/contextExisting}"
  })`

Comment: The second thing you can try is to invoke `this.getModel("detailModel").getData()` in your view and check the result.

Comment: The labelname is not the Problem. That works fine. The Property-Binding doesn´t work.

Comment: With `this.getModel("detailModel")` there is an error that says that that´s not a function.With `sap.ui.getCore().getModel("detailModel")` there is a result.

Comment: `this` must be your view

Comment: ok tried this instat of `this` : `console.log(sap.ui.getCore().byId("detail").getController().getView().getModel("detailModel"));` result is `undefined`

Comment: Then I suppose your model is not inherited by the view

Comment: Working Example: https://jsbin.com/seforoyoyi/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks verry much. It is working now. In place of `sap.ui.getCore().setModel` I´m now using `this.setModel` on the view. So that `this.getModel` is not longer`undefined`. But I still don´t understand why `sap.ui.getCore().setModel` doesn´t work because in my understanding with `sap.ui.getCore().setModel` is set a Model globally so that i can fetch this in any view within the app... .

Answer (score 0):

The following code must work:

```
var label = new sap.m.Label({
      text: {labelName}
  }).bindProperty("visible",
{path : "detailModel>/contextExisting",
formatter: function(x){
console.log(x); //should read 'false'
return x;
}});

console.log(label); //check here. What models do you see in the 'oModels' 
                    //property, and the 'oPropagatedProperties/oModels' property? One of these must 
                    //contain your model.

return label;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a context, following is the correct synthax (without a slash)

```
.bindProperty("visible","{detailModel>contextExisting}");
```

Please check that the context of your "detailModel" is set. The context of default model isn`t use here.

```
$.sap.log.info(label.getBindingContext("detailModel").getPath());
```

or better to prevent exceptions

```
$.sap.log.info(label.getBindingContext("detailModel") && label.getBindingContext("detailModel").getPath());
```